# How is possible for AngularJS to recognise the name of a module?

Tags: angularjs, web

I'm currently learning AngularJS, but I'm a little confused. This is the very very basic exercise about assigning a controller to a view vía `ng-controller`. My web app consis of two files (index.html and js.js):

index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body ng-app="simpleApp">
    <h1>Welcome to my website!</h1>

    <div ng-controller="mainController">
        <h2>This is my personal website :)</h2>
    </div>

    <script src="lib/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="js.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

js.js:

```
var myApp = angular.module("simpleApp", []);

myApp.controller("mainController", function() {
    console.log("It controller really works!!");
});
```

In most of the angular examples that I see, the global scope variable for the angular module has both the same name. But I use different (`myApp` for the variable and `simpleApp` for the name of the module) I'm a little weird about the code because I assign the `mainController`, it's AngularJS detecting it via myApp variable or via simpleApp module? Why it doesn't work if `ng-app=myApp`?.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax `angular.module('name', []);` creates and returns a new module.  Notice the `[]` which defines an empty collection of module dependencies.  That is important because when you create a module, you need this.

However, you can use a similar syntax to add controllers to modules:

```
angular.module('name').controller(...
```

This is usually preferred because it doesn't pollute the global scope and it makes more sense once you start to split modules across physical files.

Now to your question.  Your module name `simpleApp` is *always* the name you will use to refer to your newly created module. `myApp` just holds a reference to the module with that name.

So, the name that Angular uses will always be `simpleApp`.  You will use that name in `ng-app` (as you've done), and anywhere else where the module name might be required.  For example, if you add your module as a dependency of another module it would look like:

```
angular.module('anotherModule', ['simpleApp']);
```

> detecting it via myApp variable or via simpleApp module

Angular is detecting via the name `simpleApp`.

Comment: First of all, thanks! :). Well, given your explanation I suppose that myApp variable that hold that module is only necessary for adding more controllers, modules, etc. to that module inside the js.js because the index.html (which has the ng-app) detects directly via module name), I'm in the correct way?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  However, if `js.js` is loaded first, then all other scripts loaded after will be able to address the variable `myApp`.  That is what I meant about polluting the global scope.